# JavaScript code not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am trying to implement the read more and read less feature on `click` on link for my articles app in `Django`. But my `JavaScript` code is not responding when I click on the read more link.

Here are my files.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $el, $p, $up, $ps;

  $('.button').on("click", function() {
    $el = $(this);
    $p = $el.parent();
    $up = $p.parent();
    $ph = $up.find(".para");
    $ps = $up.find(".rest-content");

    if ($ps.is(':hidden')) {
      $p.load(function() {
        $ps.show(), $el.html("(read-less)"), $ph.hide(), console.log("It worked");
      });
    } else {
      $ps.hide();
      $el.html("(read-more)");
      $ph.show();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
{% if article.post|length > 300 %}
  <p class="para">{{ article.post|truncatechars:300}}</p>
  <p class="rest-content">{{ article.post}}</p>
  <p class="read-more"><a href="#" class="button" >(read more)</a></p><br>
{% else %}
  <p class="para">{{ article.post }}</p> <br>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “not responding”? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. I’m not a jQuery expert, but how do you expect that `$p.load` call to work? Isn’t that just an event listener?

Comment: Only elements loading content from external resources (like `img` and `iframe`) are triggering `load` event. `a` element is not a button, use buttons as buttons and anchors as links. Also, you're using the variables in the click event handler only, it's better to declare them within the function too.

Answer (score 0):

Many of your jQuery calls do not have the correct syntax. For example:

```
$ph = $up.find(".para");
```

Should be

```
$ph = $($up).find(".para");
```

In order to use the jQuery functionality. Re-write your code with this in mind and see if that works :)

Comment: I edited my code as per the above mentioned solution but then it is not running. Actually I had this code of mine running before and showing the expected output but suddenly the java script part is not responding for this or any other script written in it.